# Hard disk shows up only sometimes

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

One of my hard disks does not show up after booting sometimes. If I use the computer a bit and the reboot, it tends to show up. Sometimes immediately rebooting 5-6 times will not cause it to show up. More than half the time it shows up fine.

When it does show up its got some big games on it that run smooth and fine, so I'm assuming there's no corruption or serious cable problems, but I can't guess as to what's going on. Once it shows up it stays and works with no problems whatsoever.

This has been ongoing for around 6 months. Any ideas as to what could cause such infrequent behavior?

Comment: Possible hard disk failure. Check your hard drives for SMART errors [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](//superuser.com/q/29240), and [What is the easiest method of checking SMART status for your hard drive?](//superuser.com/q/14803). Report back with the results.

Comment: HDD's motherboard probably overheated, try to cool down this HDD with fan, if it get better, then it defiantly  issue with some chip on this HDD

Comment: The computer is being booted after 8 hours of no use in a cold room. There should be no heat problems.

Comment: SpeedFan short test gave no errors, running extended test.

Comment: What type/mode of HDD is it ?

Comment: WDC WD5000AAKS-65A7B0 - NTFS Sata optical 500g, at least 4-5 years old I think. Listed as a primary, used as a secondary. Some old win7 OS data on it, even some boot files on it now that I look.

Comment: extended test showed no errors =o

Comment: image of the results: http://imgur.com/a/AHDnq

Comment: it's almost as if it works better after the machine warms up >_>